# Error attempting to install R packages: malformed universal file: slice content is not mach-o or a static library file

Tags: r, macos, gcc, rstudio, homebrew

When trying to install R packages (in both RStudio and command-line R) that involve genetic sequence analysis, i.e. ape, adegenet, spider, I get the following error:

```
ld: malformed universal file: slice content is not mach-o or a static library file '/usr/local/lib/libgfortran.dylib'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ape.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ape’
```

I've tried a number of things: Reinstalling Xcode, reinstalling gcc via Homebrew, and none of them solve the problem. I get the above error when installing ape, but intermittently get linkage warnings attempting to install ape and always get them when installing adegenet or spider (e.g. `ld: warning: object file (decorana.o) was built for newer macOS version (12.5) than being linked (12.0)`). I suspect there may be an issue with conflicting versions of gcc existing on my machine. For example, the command `which gcc` in terminal returns `/usr/bin/gcc` although brew-installed gcc components are found in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/`. I'm confused about why this is the case because `/usr/local/` is listed in advance of `/usr/bin/` in my path. Of course, this may not be the only issue.

I'm using MacOS 12.5, RStudio 2022.07.0, R 4.2.1, and brew is completely up to date (e.g. brew outdated returns nothing).

Any and all help would be much appreciated!

---

The full output from an attempt to install ape in RStudio is as follows:

```
> install.packages("ape")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ape_5.6-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1754486 bytes (1.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.7 MB

* installing *source* package ‘ape’ ...
** package ‘ape’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c BIONJ.c -o BIONJ.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c NNI.c -o NNI.o
clang++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c SPR.c -o SPR.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c additive.c -o additive.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c ape.c -o ape.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c bNNI.c -o bNNI.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c bionjs.c -o bionjs.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c bipartition.c -o bipartition.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c bitsplits.c -o bitsplits.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c delta_plot.c -o delta_plot.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c dist_dna.c -o dist_dna.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c dist_nodes.c -o dist_nodes.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c ewLasso.c -o ewLasso.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c heap.c -o heap.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c mat_expo.c -o mat_expo.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c me.c -o me.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c me_balanced.c -o me_balanced.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c me_ols.c -o me_ols.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c mvr.c -o mvr.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c mvrs.c -o mvrs.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c nj.c -o nj.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c njs.c -o njs.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c pic.c -o pic.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c plot_phylo.c -o plot_phylo.o
clang++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c prop_part.cpp -o prop_part.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c rTrait.c -o rTrait.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c read_dna.c -o read_dna.o
clang++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c reorder_Rcpp.cpp -o reorder_Rcpp.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c reorder_phylo.c -o reorder_phylo.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c treePop.c -o treePop.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c tree_build.c -o tree_build.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c tree_phylo.c -o tree_phylo.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c triangMtd.c -o triangMtd.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c triangMtds.c -o triangMtds.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c ultrametric.c -o ultrametric.o
clang++ -std=gnu++14 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/xz/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o ape.so BIONJ.o NNI.o RcppExports.o SPR.o additive.o ape.o bNNI.o bionjs.o bipartition.o bitsplits.o delta_plot.o dist_dna.o dist_nodes.o ewLasso.o heap.o mat_expo.o me.o me_balanced.o me_ols.o mvr.o mvrs.o nj.o njs.o pic.o plot_phylo.o prop_part.o rTrait.o read_dna.o reorder_Rcpp.o reorder_phylo.o treePop.o tree_build.o tree_phylo.o triangMtd.o triangMtds.o ultrametric.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/lib -lRlapack -L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib -lopenblas -L/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin21/11 -L/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/gcc -L/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11 -lgfortran -lemutls_w -lquadmath -lm -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/lib -lR -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: malformed universal file: slice content is not mach-o or a static library file '/usr/local/lib/libgfortran.dylib'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ape.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ape’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/ape’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ape’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/4n/0ghjrzsd4g393zjlgxy9ympc0000gn/T/Rtmpot4Zet/downloaded_packages’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I deleted `/usr/local/lib/libgfortran.dylib` as it was just a link and this caused the installer to find `libgfortran.dylib` in a different directory and the install worked with only the linked file warnings. I'm calling this a win.